# Maven Resources plugin couldn't overwrite read-only file issue

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

It seems to me maven-resources-plugin copy-resource couldn't overwrite read-only files.

The file is read-only because our svn require an "lock" to make it read-write.

It doesn't work if i added "`<overwrite>true</overwrite>`" (I understand this is not for this purpose).

Comment: Have you created the files in target folder or in an other folder? Or trying to overwrite within source folder (src/*)

Comment: I was trying to overwrite a file within src/ folder by another file inside src/subDir.

Comment: Ok. Than it's clear that it's not possible with locking.

Answer (score 1):

Working with locks in relationship with SVN and source code does not make sense. And of course the maven-resources-plugin does not support this misuse. The simple answer to this question is: Don't use locks on source files.

Comment: I am also against the 'lock', but we don't have a choice. Currently I use the clean plugin to remove that file as a workaround.